# Source .vimrc command not found Amir Salihefendic

Tags: bash, vim

I am using the [The ultimate Vim configuration: vimrc](https://github.com/amix/vimrc/blob/master/vimrcs/basic.vim)!

When tried to `source basic.vim` or the `extended.vim`, this warning message is shown and several empty files, such as Text, Color,etc, will be created.

It seems due to the comment problem of these two files.

Vim version: 7.4.5

: command not found
       Amir Salihefendic
: command not found

: command not found
bash:        5.0 - 29/05/12 15:43:36
: No such file or directory
 Blog_post 
: command not found

: command not found
       Get this config, nice color schemes and lots of plugins!
: command not found
       Install the awesome version from:
: command not found
bash:
: No such file or directory
 Syntax_highlighted
: command not found

: command not found
bash:        http://amix.dk/vim/vimrc.txt
: No such file or directory
 Sections
: command not found
    -> VIM user interface
: command not found
    -> Files and backups
: command not found
    -> Visual mode related
: command not found
    -> Status line
: command not found
    -> vimgrep searching and cope displaying
: command not found
    -> Misc
: command not found

---

solutions:
Confused `:!so %` with `:so %`,because ex-commands is different with in-commands.

Use try catch is a good alternative to ignore some problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you are running `source .vimrc` inside your bash shell instead of doing the same inside your `.vimrc` file.

Once you download `basic.vim` from the website you linked, you want to put it somewhere (either in your home directory or another directory), and then add the line `source basic.vim` inside your `~/.vimrc` file.

Comment: I tried to use `!source %` in .vimrc, but still get the following errors:           
/home/kamel/vimConf/vimrcs/basic.vim: line 2: $'\n': command not found
/home/kamel/vimConf/vimrcs/basic.vim: line 4: $'       Amir Salihefendic\n': command not found
/home/kamel/vimConf/vimrcs/basic.vim: line 6: $'\n': command not found
/home/kamel/vimConf/vimrcs/basic.vim: line 8:        5.0 - 29/05/12 15:43:36

Comment: Don't use `!source %`, just use `source %`. The `!` means to execute external command.

Comment: Now this error appears: line   66:  E174: Command already exists: add ! to replace it.    line 66 is: `command W w !sudo tee % > /dev/null`  Does it stop once this error occurs while leaving the  the rest .vimrc file unprocessed?

Comment: It probably conflicts with something already defined in your `vimrc`. If you don't need that command, just comment that line out. Otherwise, replace `command` with `command!` to overwrite any previous definition.

Comment: @Karnel, I believe it stops on errors, but I'm not 100% sure.